# How do I properly reference files in subdirectories (in xampp) for PHP, CSS, etc. on localhost?

Tags: php, css, directory, xampp, localhost

I'm running XAMPP on win7 to test fairly simple sites using PHP/MySQL/AJAX, and have run into the problem of not being able to reference files correctly.

I know that `C:\xampp\htdocs` is "equivalent" to `http://localhost/`, and I have a project subdirectory in `C:\xampp\htdocs\lorem_ipsum` (which is `http://localhost/lorem_ipsum/`). Within that are some more folders (one for php scripts, one for css stylesheets, etc).

I'm having problems referencing files in these subdirectories.

For example, in lorem_ipsum/index.php I use the line:

```
require_once 'http://localhost/lorem_ipsum/php/login.php'
```

Which creates the error:

```
Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\lorem_ipsum\index.php on line 13

Warning: require_once(http://localhost/lorem_ipsum/php/login.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\lorem_ipsum\index.php on line 13

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost/lorem_ipsum/php/login.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\lorem_ipsum\index.php on line 13
```

By googling around I've gathered that it's some sort of "filesharing/security" issue, but I have absolutely no idea what that means or how to fix it (I'm still very much a beginner).

When I use the following CSS, for example:

```
background-image:url('http://localhost/lorem_ipsum/images/bg.png')
```

The background is white, not 'bg.png'. Same if I use `'./images/bg.png'`.

I've tried all sorts of different ways to reference the files, and none have worked. I also tried taking down any firewalls and that didn't work, either.

My ultimate question is: Why all the problems having to do with file references?

Secondary questions: Are the PHP and CSS errors related, or have I screwed them both up that badly? How can I stop this from happening? Is there a setting in apache/php that needs to change, or am I just coding it wrong?

Comment: you need to either require it via absolute or relative to the current directory. Do not use HTTP to require files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you should reference files from the Document_Root that is specified (C:\xampp\htdocs in your case). So try

```
require_once "/lorem_ipsum/phplogin.php";
```

The url in the css *should* work if the file is being hosted properly. But you can also try a relative path like:

```
background-image:url('/lorem_ipsum/images/bg.png');
```

Comment: Using a relative will help when you want to move the site to some real hosting too. That way you don't have to rewrite the code base they have another file structure on the server than you do.

Comment: Aha! When I tried using relative paths earlier, it didn't work, and I figured out why - for some reason include_path was set to something that wasn't the htdocs folder. `set_include_path('.;C\xampp\htdocs\lorem_ipsum');` and `require_once '/php/login.php';` seem to work, though of course now I need to finally get down to debugging login.php :) 

As for the CSS... still doesn't work. Is there a sort of "set_includes_path" for CSS, I wonder? The .css file is in /lorem_ipsum/css, if that matters. (I know that index.php references the css file correctly, this is the only css that doesn't work)

Comment: CSS doesn't use any notion of an include path. It compares the path against your root url and makes another HTTP request. Make sure that you can access your files by doing `http://localhost/lorem_ipsum/images/bg.png`. If that does not work, then that's your problem, not the way that the file path is stated

Comment: Yes, I can get to the file just fine by doing as you suggested. I am also sure the CSS is referenced correctly, since every other change I make in the .css file applies just fine. Guess I'll tinker around with things a bit more and see if I can't find the problem in an unexpected place.

Answer (score 0):

give defines of Variable to require_once command, because HTTP:// protocol is not allow on much Server on PHP ini to reduce some conflict and Trouble .

```
<pre>
&lt;?
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "php/login.php")

//next script here..... 

?&gt;
</pre>
```

or maybe you want make include command :

```
<pre>
&lt;?
include "php/login.php";

//do something here..


?&gt;
</pre>
```

ref : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php / http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

and for css is :

```
 <pre>
background-image:url('images/bg.png')
</pre>
```